# Active class not set to `li` with specific index()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `UL LI` menu some `li` have `ul` children.

Each time root `li` clicked i add `.active` to them and then save a `li` index() to cookie,

The problem is after I save the index() to cookie, the `active` class set to children index()
for example myclicked root `li` is 7.

But the css go to the children of `li` 6 and active class add to first `li` child from index 6,
but i want find root `li` with index 7.

My code is:

```
$(function () {

        var foo = $.cookie("test");

        if (foo == null) {
            foo = 0;
        }

        $("#MenuArchiv").find("li").removeClass("activ");

        $("#MenuArchiv li").eq(foo).addClass("activ");


        $("#MenuArchiv li").click(function () {
            foo = $(this).index();
            $("#MenuArchiv").find("li").removeClass("activ");
             $(this).addClass("activ");
             $.cookie("test", foo, { expires: 10 });
        });
});
```

hope to understand my mean :)

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle of your scenario with screenshots of what you want and how it is behaving?

Comment: can i use jquery cookie in jsfiddle?

Comment: you have to ideally check its right side bar to know the details. - @Radian

Comment: @Radian yes as an external source... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M6u9b/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks i make a jsfiddle

Comment: here is JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M6u9b/5/

Comment: click on the item1,2,3,4,5 and refresh,you see that's work,now click on the item 7 or item8 and refresh, that not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the way you use index() gives you the index() of that element in it's parent. But you use eq() on an object that contains all li (even the ones inside other li-elements. So you have two totally different arrays that you want to use the same index on.

change your line with the index()-call to the following and it should work:

```
foo = $("#MenuArchiv li").index(this);
```

this makes the same as you do with eq(), it asks for the index of that element in the object of all li-elements